# Use a function in different file and different namespace in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am struggling with my first steps in C++. Already asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680612/how-to-use-a-function-in-different-file-in-visual-c) question, but did not get the full answer specifically about namespace.

I did the following.

1. In Visual Studio 2015 created am empty project(New Project -> Visual C++ -> Empty Project)
2. Then I added two files in Source.cpp and PrintFunc.cpp whose respective contents are as follows.

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int PrintHello();
extern int tempCount;

void main()
{
    int i;
    PrintHello();
    cout << tempCount << endl;
    cout << "Hello from main" << endl;
}
```

PrintFunc.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int tempCount = 111;

int PrintHello()
{
    cout << "Hello from Source1" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is compiling perfectly. 
Now I am learning about namespaces, so I just tried to put the contents of the second file in a namespace as follows.

PrintFunc.cpp (modified)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    int tempCount = 111;

    int PrintHello()
    {
        cout << "Hello from Source1" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And now I modified the Source.cpp also to reflect the namespaces introduction in the previous snippets.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int MyNameSpace::PrintHello();
extern int MyNameSpace::tempCount;

void main()
{
    int i;
    PrintHello();
    cout << tempCount << endl;
    cout << "Hello from main" << endl;
}
```

This simply does not compile. Can someone please kindly correct me. My objective is to understand namespace concept in c++. Also I have good exp with C#.

Comment: You're calling them from the global namespace. Try `MyNameSpace::PrintHello();` Or you could write `using namespace MyNameSpace;` but then it's useless to even have the namespace in the first place...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem that compiler does not know about namespace `MYSpace` when compiling `Source.cpp`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    int PrintHello();
    extern int tempCount;
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    MyNameSpace::PrintHello();
    cout << MyNameSpace::tempCount << endl;
    cout << "Hello from main" << endl;
}
```

But this sample is `useless`. It work only because you have only one consumer `.cpp`.

You should use `.h` file and then include it (`PrintFunc.h`) in `Source.cpp` and any other `.cpp` when you want to use that funtions.

I'll write an example:

Print.h

```
#pragma once

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    int PrintHello();
    extern int tempCount;
}
```

Notice that we dont't use additional `includes` and `using namespace` here. We would use `includes` only to use some classes in `functions` `interfaces`.
`using namespace` could "spoil" consumer's `.cpp` or `.h`.

Print.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Print.h"

using namespace std;

int MyNameSpace::tempCount = 111;

int MyNameSpace::PrintHello()
{
    cout << "Hello from Source1" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here we can set any `include` it will not touch any other files.

And consumer `.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Print.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    MyNameSpace::PrintHello();
    cout << MyNameSpace::tempCount << endl;
    cout << "Hello from main" << endl;
}
```

VS specific: `#pragma once` and for VS you have to `#include "stdafx.h"` at first line in any `.cpp`

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, your solution is working. Just give me some time I shall take a decision to mark this as an ans.

Comment: Don't hurry. Just remember that keyword `extern` always should be in `.h`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to supply namespace name when using its members. Or use `using namespace` directive.

```
void main()
{
    int i;
    MyNameSpace::PrintHello();
    cout << MyNameSpace::tempCount << endl;
    cout << "Hello from main" << endl;
}
```

However, for it to work namespace should be declared in the separate `.h` file and it should be included in your `source.cpp`

Comment: Doesn't work: "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2653 'MyNameSpace': is not a class or namespace name CPPConsoleApp cppconsoleapp.cpp 7 
"

Comment: Its not still working, can you please update with the full code?

Comment: I've updated my mark :) @Vivek try my example with `.h`.

Answer (score 0):

So finally here it is that I have settled for based on [Dmitriy Zapevalov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37694138/1977871) answer.

First Print.h

```
#pragma once

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    int PrintHello();
    extern int tempCount;
}
```

Next PrintFunc.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Print.h"

using namespace std;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    int tempCount = 111;
    int PrintHello()
    {
        cout << "Hello from Source1" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

PrintFunc.cpp can also be like this as an alternative.

PrintFunc.cpp (alternative)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Print.h"

using namespace std;

int MyNameSpace::tempCount = 111;
int MyNameSpace::PrintHello()
{
    cout << "Hello from Source1" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And finally Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Print.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace MyNameSpace;

void main()
{
    PrintHello();
    cout << tempCount << endl;
    cout << "Hello from main" << endl;
}
```

Source.cpp can also be like this as an alternative.

Source.cpp (alternative)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Print.h"

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    MyNameSpace::PrintHello();
    cout << MyNameSpace::tempCount << endl;
    cout << "Hello from main" << endl;
}
```